# "was run from" or "ran from"?

Tags: grammar

1. The Quick Cash Campaign was run from May to August.

or

2. The Quick Cash Campaign ran from May to August.

Number 2 sounds right to me but I'm not sure which one is really correct.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Both are fine, grammatically.

Comment: They are both fine but are slightly different in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 uses the passive voice, and in that form you might consider adding the name of the agent who ran the campaign, for example: "The Quick Cash Campaign was run from May to August by our dedicated volunteers." In this form the emphasis of the sentence becomes the agents rather than the campaign.

Number 2 is better when the agents are relatively unimportant, and your emphasis is intended to be on the campaign itself.

As written, number 2 is better because number 1 leaves the reader (this reader, at least) with a nagging question: "was run by whom?"